# PHP socket_read to int

Tags: php, sockets, casting, int, return

if i use:

```
 socket_read($socket, 1024);
```

I don't know what type of variable it returns. I want to make it to an int, but i don't know how.
The Server respons only a number (35).
If i echo it, i get 35. If i cast it to "(int)" i get 0. intval returns 0 too.
I have tried to cast it to string, and pick the first letter (3) but it returned 0. Substr doesn't work too.
I want to have an int value, so that i can calculate things with this value. I need an int to calculate the prozentage of this value from another value.
What can i do?

**EDIT:**

Fixed it in JAVA SERVER SOCKET CODE whith:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream());
```

instead of using

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: What if it echoes something like `<p>35</p>` or just some invisible to you symbol? Which is parsed by HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Why not read the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php). It returns a string.

Try `print_r` to find out the details of that string. Might be in binary?!

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit - Each to their own?!

Comment: i read the manual page but it doesn't work as string. print_r only returns "35"

Comment: @user2517393 - Why not add the output from the `var_dump/print_r?

Comment: @Ed Heal var_dump() returned: string(5) "126". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [manual](http://php.net/socket_read), socket_read always returns a string. You should try using `var_dump()` to check the real value of the variable.

Did you try to sum any number to that variable? In the autocast it may work.

Comment: tryed it, but if i sum 1 to the variable, it only returns the 1 without any sum. var_dump() returned: string(5) "35". What does this mean?

Comment: Maybe the string starts with 3 spaces, html will not show them. Remove whitespace using the [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function

Comment: if i use trim() and var_dump() i get: string(3) "35". $variable{2} returns me "3"

Comment: That's the most strange thing I ever saw in PHP. There it says string(3), but $var[2] returns 3! You're using trim() inside var_dump(), right?

Comment: My fault, i meant $var[1] returnes 3

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the string contains additional whitespace that prevents PHP from converting it  to a number.

Therefore I suggest you use the [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to remove whitespace before converting it to a number. Or you could use a regular expression to remove all non-numeric characters `$out = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/g", "", $in)`

If this still doesn't work and `var_dump` doesn't help you either, I'd suggest to sniff the network traffic using WireShark to inspect the packet coming from the server. If you're in control of what the server sends, use a decent serialization method like XML or JSON instead of inventing some protocol yourself.

Comment: tryed it but convertion doesn't work. if i get "$variable{0}" i get nothing. If i use "$variable{1}" i get "3"

Comment: Read manual for trim, it can remove other characters too. You'll have to use WireShark to see what kind of character is sent before the number.

Comment: Added regular expression method to answer in case trim lets you down

Comment: "$out = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/g", "", $in)" and "var_dump($out);" returns "NULL" on website

Comment: fixed it with {PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream());} in java

Comment: So you have control over what the server does: use JSON or XML serialization!